# Databinding items to Canvas

Tags: wpf, data-binding, canvas

I have a userControl that contains a canvas. I would like to databind items to it so they are positioned automagically.

[Here's](http://www.iconstructions.be/myblog/avalon-position-data-binding.aspx) a great example that shows how to databind items on **a** canvas, but I want it to work on **my** specific userControl. (I believe it's not possible to specify a userControl in a ItemsPanelTemplate)

Comment: So . . . what is your question?

Comment: I want to databind items to the canvas in my existing userControl, and not create a new standard one.

Answer (score 0):

One option for you, depending on what your `UserControl` does, is to make your own `Canvas` subclass, which you can then use in your `ItemsPanel` (any subclass of Panel works). This assumes that all you were doing with your UserControl was positioning items.

If you really want to use a `UserControl`, an option off the top of my head would be to add an `ItemsControl` into your `UserControl` (which has the Canvas as the ItemsPanel) and bind the items to it via `TemplateBinding`